# Learning OOP javascript - critique my class that creates a 'favourites' list

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I'm trying to improve my javascript coding style and want to start writing my code more object-oriented. The code below is getting a JSON-stringified list of locations from a cookie and appending a `li` to a list for each location. I would appreciate some helpful critique and any general pointers. I have some questions too:

1. Am I using `self` correctly? It feels like I'm over using it i.e. on function calls but when its not there I cannot access those functions. Some plugins I've used are written in this way and some are not, why is that?
2. If I wanted to use this as a static class, how can I code it differently instead of instantiating it?

I have experience with vb/c# if that helps when explaining things.

```
var favourites = function(list, settings) {
    var self = this;

    self.options = {
        maxitems: 5,
        cookiename: "fav-locations"
    };
    self._$list = $(list) || $();
    self._locations = [];

    //extend defaults with any settings
    $.extend(self.options, settings);

    //load the locations
    var init = function (aryLocations) {
        var index = 0;
        if (aryLocations) {
            for (index; index < aryLocations.length; index++) {
                self.add(aryLocations[index]);
            }

            self.loadLocations();
            self.bindRemoveButtons();
        }
    };

    self.add = function (loc) {
        if ((self._locations.length < self.options.maxitems) && self.find(loc)) {
            self._locations.push(loc);
            $.cookie(self.options.cookiename, JSON.stringify(self._locations), { path: '/' });
        }
        else {
            console.log('exceeded limit');
        }
    };

    self.remove = function (loc) {
        var location_index = self.find(loc);
        console.log(location_index);
        if (location_index > -1) {
            self._locations.splice(location_index, 1);
            $.cookie(self.options.cookiename, JSON.stringify(self._locations), { path: '/' });
            self.setCount();
        }
        else {
            console.log('location not found.');
        }
    };

    self.populateLocations = function () {
        self.clearList();

        $.each(self._locations, function (index, item) {

            //get this locations name and id - format here is: name|id
            var location = {
                name: item.split('|')[0] || '',
                id: item.split('|')[1] || 0
            };

            //create a new li element
            var $thisItem = $('<li/>').appendTo(self._$list[0]).addClass('wrap');

            $thisItem.data("loc", item);

            $thisItem.html('<button class="remove-icon">&times;</button> <a href="/home/search-handler.asp">' + location.name + '</a>');
        });
    };

    self.setCount = function () {
        //set count value
        var countelem = self._$list.prev().find('.count');
        if (countelem.length > 0) { countelem.text(self._locations.length); };
    };

    self.loadLocations = function () {
        self.populateLocations();
        self.setCount();
    };

    self.clearList = function () {
        $(self._$list).find('li').remove();
    };

    self.find = function (loc) {
        var location_index = -1;
        for (var index = 0; index < self._locations.length; index++) {
            if (self._locations[index] === loc) {
                location_index = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        return location_index;
    };

    //remove button click handler
    self.bindRemoveButtons = function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.remove-icon', function (e) {
            var elem = $(this).parent();
            e.preventDefault();
            elem.slideUp('fast', function () {
                self.remove(elem.data("loc"));
                elem.remove();
            });
        });
    };

    //init the list
    init(JSON.parse($.cookie(self.options.cookiename)));
};

var favLocs = new favourites("ul.favourites-list", { tester: 1 });
```

---

**UPDATE**: Using the feedback below I've refactored the code implementing as much as I can. The events are still there as I'm not sure how to resolve that one but I think the code has improved.

```
var Favourites = (function ($) {
    'use strict';

    //constructor
    function Favourites(list, settings) {
        this.options = {
            maxitems: 5,
            cookiename: "fav-locations",
            searchurl: null
        };
        this._$list = $(list) || $();
        this._locations = [];

        //extend defaults with any settings
        $.extend(this.options, settings);

        //add locations to the array
        var index = 0,
            locations = JSON.parse($.cookie(this.options.cookiename));

        for (index; index < locations.length; index++) {
            this.add(locations[index]);
        }

        this.loadLocations();
        this.bindRemoveButtons();
        this.bindLocationLinkHandler();
    }
    //methods
    Favourites.prototype = {
        add: function (loc) {
            if ((this._locations.length < this.options.maxitems) && this.find(loc)) {
                this._locations.push(loc);
                $.cookie(this.options.cookiename, JSON.stringify(this._locations), { path: '/' });
            } else {
                console.log("exceeded limit");
            }
        },
        remove: function (loc) {
            var location_index = this.find(loc);
            console.log(location_index);
            if (location_index > -1) {
                this._locations.splice(location_index, 1);
                $.cookie(this.options.cookiename, JSON.stringify(this._locations), { path: '/' });
                this.setCount();
            } else {
                console.log("location not found.");
            }
        },
        populateLocations: function () {
            var self = this;

            this.clearList();

            $.each(this._locations, function (item) {

                //get this locations name and id - format here is: name|id
                var location = {
                    name: item.split('|')[0] || '',
                    id: item.split('|')[1] || 0
                },
                    //create a new li element
                    $thisItem = $('<li/>').appendTo(self._$list[0]).addClass("wrap");

                $thisItem.data("location", location.name);
                $thisItem.data("location-id", location.id);

                $thisItem.html('<button class="remove-icon">&times;</button> <a href="' + self.options.searchurl + '" class="fav-link">' + location.name + '</a>');
            });
        },
        setCount: function () {
            //set count value
            var countelem = this._$list.prev().find('.count');
            if (countelem.length > 0) { countelem.text(this._locations.length); }
        },
        loadLocations: function () {

            if ($(".search-nav:visible .current").length > 0) {
                $(".favourites, .search-box").fadeIn(300);
            }

            this.populateLocations();
            this.setCount();
        },
        clearList: function () {
            $(this._$list).find('li').remove();
        },
        find: function (loc) {
            var location_index = -1,
                index = 0;
            for (index; index < this._locations.length; index++) {
                if (this._locations[index] === loc) {
                    location_index = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return location_index;
        },
        bindRemoveButtons: function () {
            var self = this;
            $(document).on('click', '.remove-icon', function (e) {
                var elem = $(this).parent();
                e.preventDefault();
                elem.slideUp('fast', function () {
                    self.remove(elem.data("location") + '|' + elem.data("location-id"));
                    elem.remove();
                });
            });
        },
        bindLocationLinkHandler: function () {
            var self = this;
            $(document).on("click", ".fav-link", function (e) {
                var elem = $(this).parent();

                self.forwardToSection(elem.data("location"), elem.data("location-id"), e);
            });
        },
        forwardToSection: function (loc, locid, event) {
            var section = $(".search-nav:visible .current a").text(),
                qs = '?loc_Location=' + encodeURI(loc) + '&loc_exactlocation=' + locid;

            if (section) {
                if (event) {
                    event.currentTarget.href = event.currentTarget.href + qs + '&searchSite=' + section.toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    window.location = this.options.searchurl + qs + '&searchSite=' + section.toLowerCase();
                }
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Please select a section above");
            }
        }
    };

    return Favourites;
}(jQuery));

var favLocs = new Favourites("ul.favourites-list", { searchurl: "/home/search-handler.asp" });
```

Comment: Would jQuery's $.proxy help here? You can wrap everything the a function and use this as the target in the second argument.

Comment: What do you mean "use this as the target in the second argument"? What would this achieve?

Comment: Would avoid the need to use a middleman "self" variable. Check the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to consider (after a first, superficial look at your code):

- Stick to the conventions: A constructor starts with an UpperCase, and is camelCased from their on. `Favourites` would be a better var name, because it signals a constructor, and requires the `new` keyword.
- `self`, though not a reserved keyword is used by some JS engines for particular purposes. using `self` *can* lead to unexpected behaviour. Perhaps consider using `var that = this;` instead.
- Use the `prototype` for methods, to avoid creating too many function objects.
- `self` isn't required all the time, but it's safer. You're not using it badly, you're using it, but don't seem to know what it's for.
- Binding event handlers (`self.bindRemoveButtons`) is *not* the job of an object, or any of its methods. It's not because you're using the `new` keyword, and methods, that you're writing good, OO code. Besides, JS is prototype-based, using traditional OO techniques in JS is like a barber, using a scythe to cut your hair...
- The `init` function needn't be declared for each instance, use a closure.
- You have no guarantee that `$` will be the jQuery object, use a closure.

Now, some examples to help you on your way:

```
var Favourites = (function($)//pass jQ object to closure
{
    'use strict';
    var init = function()
    {
        //the init function here.
    };
    function Favourites(list, settings)
    {//properties here...
        this._$list = $(list) || $();
        init();//call closure function init declared above ^^
    }
    Favourites.prototype.setCount = function()
    {
        //methods belong to the prototype
    };
    return Favourites;//return reference to constructor
}(jQuery));
```

This is what a more complex constructor definition in JS looks like.

*Update:*
Your updated code looks good. Honestly. It's not perfect, but then, in programming, perfection is more of a subjective thing. Personally, I rarely, if not never write constructors. I just use object literals and the module pattern.

You've looked into closures. Great, I get the impression you get what they're for, but you don't yet see all the use-cases for them. For example the `bindLocationLinkHandler` method, and for that matter, all the DOM-related methods, contain `$(document)`. What this code does, essentially is call the jQuery init funtion, and constructs a jQuery wrapper object around the `document` object. Why would you do this over and over? why not wrap all those prototype methods in a simple closure like this:

```
(function($doc)
{
    Favourites.prototype.bindLocationLinkHandler = function()
    {
        $doc.on('click', ...);
    };
}($(document));//pass jQ wrapped document here
```

This'll save you a few jQ init calls. Your methods are also binding *the same handler*. Functions are first-class object in JS, construct them once, and use them everywhere. Replace, for example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fav-link", function (e)
{
    var elem = $(this).parent();
    self.forwardToSection(elem.data("location"), elem.data("location-id"), e);
});
```

with something like:

```
(function($doc)
{
    var self, handler = function(e)
    {
        var elem = $(this).parent();
        self.forwardToSection(elem.data("location"), elem.data("location-id"), e)
    };
    Favourites.prototype.bindLocationLinkHandler = function()
    {
        self = this;//DANGEROUS... won't always work
        $doc.on('click', '.fav-link', handler);
    };
}($(document)));
```

Of course, you may have spotted that, owing to there only being a single `self` closure var for all of the instances, the `self` reference won't be as reliable. It depends on whatever method you're calling and weather or not it matters if you're calling the method on the same object or not. Either way, this was just to show that you can use closures for anything, simple, primitive variables, as well as functions. In fact, you're doing just that in jQ *all the time!*:

```
$('li').each(function()
{//<-- jQ's each method accepts an function as argument
});
```

To close this rant (few, I'm all over the place), I do have 1 more thing I'd like to point out. I left it out of my initial answer because I don't want to spark a pointless, yet lively debate, but still... In for a penny, in for a pound:
If I'm honest, I'm not too keen on jQuery. There's nothing *wrong* with jQ, but it's just something that is used too much. If all you're doing is delegate a single event, and perform one or two ajax calls, you don't need jQ, in such a scenario, where you're only using 5% of a monolithic toolkit, you're better off writing a few more lines of code. The performance benefits are, often, noticeable.

In this case, one line in particular got up my nose. You're dabbling with OO JS. The point of OO is to contain certain sets of data and logic in manageable, clearly defined entities (objects). Your object `Favourites` depends on a toolkit that is anything *but* modular. An object that relies on an entire lib, just so the constructor can do what it needs to do is, IMHO, just plain silly.
Why not replace this line:

```
$.extend(this.options, settings);
```

With a simple loop:

```
for (var p in settings)
{
    this.options[p] = settings[p];
}
```

You can add checks for `settings[p]`, to ensure you're not assigning a function object to `this.options[p]`, include a line like `if (this.options.hasOwnProperty(p))` to deal with overriding of certain default properties, making sure the new values are *valid* and so on.
You could work on this code a bit more, and avoid your `Favourites` objects to depend on jQ being loaded all together, simply by doing something like:

```
this._list = document.querySelectorAll(list);
```

Most jQ selectors work with `querySelectorAll` anyway, and `querySelectorAll` is supported by IE8, even, so on the X-browser front, you're not going to have too many issues either.
A way to delegate the click event X-browser isn't that hard, either:

```
var clickHandler = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className.test(/\bremove-icon\b/))
    {//handle remove-icon class elements only
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(target.parentNode);
    }
};
if (window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}
else
{
    window.attachEvent('onclick', clickHandler);
}
```

Granted, this is a bit more verbose, but it's not that difficult, IMO. The slide effect will require a bit more work, granted, but not nearly as much as you might think. All in all, you're free to use jQ if you want, just know that whatever jQ does, vanillaJS can do, too. If you take the time, and put in the effort to learn how you can do those things in vanillaJS, you'll find that you'll learn a great deal more about how JS actually works, which will improve the quality of your code, even when you *do* decide to use jQ

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was hoping for. I've looked into closures and think I've fixed the `self` issues. I'll update my code.

Comment: @DAC84: I've added quite a bit to my initial answer, focussing more on the use of jQ, because your updated code is OK, at first glance... just some more pointers on how you can use closures to make your code even more performant, really

Comment: So basically you are telling the OP to write his own `$.extend()` ? Sounds far-fetched, and you know it by writing 'and so on.'

Comment: @tomdemuyt: No, what I'm saying is using a monolithic toolkit like jQ, to help you write more OO code doesn't add up. OO is about writing clean, small, reusable entities. If those entities rely on a gargantuan lib, they're not really OO... when I wrote _"and so on"_ I was talking about the things the OP could do to tailor the loop to fit his needs, I hinted at what that loop _could_ do, not on what it _has_ to do

Comment: Final snarky comment; read the code of .extend() here : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js, it is clean, small and reusable and deals with traps when dealing with extending deep objects ( I mistakenly figured this is what you meant with so on ). OO is more about re-use than re-write, and I think that using $.extend() is the right call.

Comment: @tomdemuyt: Granted. I was hung up on jQ-bashing, perhaps too much to actually admit the merits of something like `$.extend` in this particular case. Still... Why not use `Object.create`, it's not entirely the same thing, but that's what I'd use here

Comment: Appreciate the update and your time @EliasVanOotegem . Re closures I get what they're for (store a reference to current context so it can be accessed in 'sub-functions') but with more reading I'll figure out their full potential. I actually started using JS before jQ so I have an understanding of it, and I've been using jQ since v1.2 for ajax etc. as back then there were many cross-browser issues. Maybe now there aren't as many issues and vanillaJS could be used, its just not viable on this project, however I get your point.

Comment: @DAC84: Fair point on the X-browser stuff. Back in the days the `new XMLHttpRequest` - `ActiveX` try-catch blocks alone were reason enough to use jQ. It's just that nowadays, many beginners seem to think jQ is another language, and they don't _understand_ JS anymore. That sends me off in a rant, like it did here, too. By no means did I mean to _"force"_ you not to use jQ, I just think it's something people use all too often, without bothering to ask themselves weather or not they really _need_ jQ at all. ah well, as always: Always happy to help, as I hope I did

Answer (score 0):

Using `self = this` is actually a bad practice. You'll end up with zillions of `self` that will mean different things at different times, and the mess will eat you up. Sadly it is used in many tutorials just because people are lazy to come up with better names.

Give it meaningful names like `user = this` or `car = this` or whatever. So much more readable and helpful to whoever struggles to understand the code. Even the abstract `myObject = this` is already better.

Comment: Disagree. `self` is a necessary evil at times. Owing to JS's ad-hoc binding, you may want to keep a reference to `this` at hand, because `this` won't always be `this`. The only argument against `self` is that it's used internally by some JS engines, even though it's not a reserved keyword. I'd use `var that = this;`, which is what Douglas Crockford does, too

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem My point was about using the meaningless word `self` for the variable, not the practice of storing the current value of `this`, which is certainly useful. Sorry if it wasn't clear.